# MySql - Alteração de servidor fez com que exiba ponto ao invés de virgula

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma aplicação `C# .net` utilizando `Mysql` como `db`, e estava hospedada na `Locaweb`. Fiz a publicação dos arquivos no servidor `SmarterAsp` e restaurei o banco de dados la também. Agora na aplicação, os campos `'double'` do banco não exibem virgula `(ex: 2,25)` e sim ponto `(ex: 2.25)`.

Essa alteração se deve a algum problema de região? Precisava de uma ajuda para entender se com alguma configuração no painel do `phpMysql` eu conseguiria resolver.

Comment: `Double` não usa `.` como separador decimal ?!

Comment: Mas quando estava na Locaweb, e eu usava o Double.Parse, se o usuário colocasse 2,5 no imput, no código convertia para 2.5. Ja no SmarterAsp ele não converte. Eu debugando na minha maquina, a conversão e feita normalmente, o que me leva a pensar em alguma configuração de região no servidor. Eu abri chamado la mas ainda nao tive resposta :(